# How to place labels in the center of grouped bars of in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I tried the following code to produce the figure below, but the labels are not centred on each bar.
How can I correct this?

```
  ggplot(data=df, aes(x = factor(x2013.engagement.score),
          group = uni.cluster, fill = uni.cluster)) + 
        labs(x = "engagement.score") +
        geom_bar(stat="bin", position=position_dodge(), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = uni.cluster, angle = 90, vjust= -0.3,stat = "bin",
              y = x2013.engagement.score + 1, group=uni.cluster),
          size = 3, position = position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

My df is

```
    year x2013.engagement.score uni.cluster
1   2014                      2         USC
2   2014                      2         JCU
3   2014                      1     QUT/ACU
4   2014                      2         JCU
5   2014                      1         JCU
6   2014                      0         CQU
7   2014                      1          GU
8   2014                      4          GU
9   2014                      1         JCU
10  2014                      1         CQU
11  2014                      1          UQ
12  2014                      1         JCU
13  2014                      1     QUT/ACU
14  2014                      2         QUT
15  2014                      2          UQ
16  2014                      4     QUT/ACU
17  2014                      2         CQU
18  2014                      2         CQU
19  2014                      2          UQ
20  2014                      1         CQU
21  2014                      3         QUT
22  2014                      3         USQ
23  2014                      1         JCU
24  2014                      1         USQ
25  2014                      1         USQ
26  2014                      4     QUT/ACU
27  2014                      0          UQ
28  2014                      3     QUT/ACU
29  2014                      3         USQ
30  2014                      3         QUT
31  2014                      3     QUT/ACU
32  2014                      2         QUT
33  2014                      0          UQ
34  2014                      0          GU
35  2014                      0         CQU
36  2014                      4          GU
37  2014                      3         CQU
38  2014                      2         USQ
39  2014                      2         JCU
40  2014                      2         USC
41  2014                      1         USQ
42  2014                      1         JCU
43  2014                      1     USQ/USC
44  2014                      1         JCU
45  2014                      1         JCU
46  2014                      1         JCU
47  2014                      1          UQ
48  2014                      2         CQU
49  2014                      1         USC
50  2014                      4          GU
51  2014                      3         CQU
52  2014                      3         QUT
53  2014                      1         USC
54  2014                      4          GU
55  2014                      2         JCU
56  2014                      1          UQ
57  2014                      1          UQ
58  2014                      4          GU
59  2014                      3          UQ
60  2014                      4          GU
61  2014                      2         CQU
62  2014                      2         JCU
63  2014                      1         JCU
64  2014                      4          GU
65  2014                      1         USC
66  2014                      3          GU
67  2014                      1         USQ
68  2014                      3         QUT
69  2014                      1         JCU
70  2014                      1         USC
71  2014                      1         USC
72  2014                      2         QUT
73  2014                      4          GU
74  2014                      1         CQU
75  2014                      1         JCU
76  2014                      4          GU
77  2014                      1         USQ
78  2014                      2         QUT
79  2014                      1         USQ
80  2014                      1         JCU
81  2014                      1          UQ
82  2014                      3         QUT
83  2014                      2         CQU
84  2014                      2         USQ
85  2014                      1          UQ
86  2014                      4     QUT/ACU
87  2014                      1         CQU
88  2014                      4         JCU
89  2014                      4          GU
90  2014                      1         JCU
91  2014                      2          GU
92  2014                      4          GU
93  2014                      1         USQ
94  2014                      1          UQ
95  2014                      3         USQ
96  2014                      1          GU
97  2014                      1         JCU
98  2014                      1          UQ
99  2014                      0         USQ
100 2014                      4         JCU
101 2014                      3         QUT
102 2014                      1         JCU
103 2014                      4          GU
104 2014                      1     USQ/USC
105 2014                      4          GU
106 2014                      2         USQ
107 2014                      1          UQ
108 2014                      4          GU
109 2014                      3         JCU
110 2014                      3         CQU
111 2014                      4          GU
112 2013                      1         USC
113 2013                      1         JCU
114 2013                      1     QUT/ACU
115 2013                      1         JCU
116 2013                      0         JCU
117 2013                      0         CQU
118 2013                      1          GU
119 2013                      4          GU
120 2013                      1         JCU
121 2013                      0         CQU
122 2013                      0          UQ
123 2013                      1         JCU
124 2013                      1     QUT/ACU
125 2013                      1         QUT
126 2013                      0          UQ
127 2013                      1     QUT/ACU
128 2013                      1         CQU
129 2013                      2         CQU
130 2013                      0          UQ
131 2013                      0         CQU
132 2013                      2         QUT
133 2013                      1         USQ
134 2013                      1         JCU
135 2013                      1         USQ
136 2013                      0         USQ
137 2013                      3     QUT/ACU
138 2013                      0          UQ
139 2013                      2     QUT/ACU
140 2013                      1         USQ
141 2013                      1         QUT
142 2013                      2     QUT/ACU
143 2013                      2         QUT
144 2013                      0          UQ
145 2013                      0          GU
146 2013                      0         CQU
147 2013                      4          GU
148 2013                      2         CQU
149 2013                      1         USQ
150 2013                      1         JCU
151 2013                      1         USC
152 2013                      1         USQ
153 2013                      1         JCU
154 2013                      1     USQ/USC
155 2013                      1         JCU
156 2013                      1         JCU
157 2013                      1         JCU
158 2013                      0          UQ
159 2013                      1         CQU
160 2013                      1         USC
161 2013                      3          GU
162 2013                      1         CQU
163 2013                      1         QUT
164 2013                      1         USC
165 2013                      4          GU
166 2013                      1         JCU
167 2013                      0          UQ
168 2013                      0          UQ
169 2013                      4          GU
170 2013                      0          UQ
171 2013                      4          GU
172 2013                      0         CQU
173 2013                      1         JCU
174 2013                      1         JCU
175 2013                      4          GU
176 2013                      1         USC
177 2013                      1          GU
178 2013                      0         USQ
179 2013                      1         QUT
180 2013                      0         JCU
181 2013                      0         USC
182 2013                      1         USC
183 2013                      0         QUT
184 2013                      4          GU
185 2013                      2         CQU
186 2013                      1         JCU
187 2013                      4          GU
188 2013                      1         USQ
189 2013                      1         QUT
190 2013                      1         USQ
191 2013                      1         JCU
192 2013                      0          UQ
193 2013                      1         QUT
194 2013                      1         CQU
195 2013                      1         USQ
196 2013                      0          UQ
197 2013                      3     QUT/ACU
198 2013                      0         CQU
199 2013                      4         JCU
200 2013                      4          GU
201 2013                      1         JCU
202 2013                      0          GU
203 2013                      3          GU
204 2013                      1         USQ
205 2013                      0          UQ
206 2013                      1         USQ
207 2013                      0          GU
208 2013                      1         JCU
209 2013                      0          UQ
210 2013                      0         USQ
211 2013                      2         JCU
212 2013                      1         QUT
213 2013                      0         JCU
214 2013                      3          GU
215 2013                      1     USQ/USC
216 2013                      3          GU
217 2013                      1         USQ
218 2013                      0          UQ
219 2013                      4          GU
220 2013                      1         JCU
221 2013                      2         CQU
222 2013                      4          GU
223 2012                      1         USC
224 2012                      0         JCU
225 2012                      1     QUT/ACU
226 2012                      0         JCU
227 2012                      0         JCU
228 2012                      0         CQU
229 2012                      0          GU
230 2012                      3          GU
231 2012                      0         JCU
232 2012                      1         CQU
233 2012                      0          UQ
234 2012                      0         JCU
235 2012                      0     QUT/ACU
236 2012                      1         QUT
237 2012                      0          UQ
238 2012                      1     QUT/ACU
239 2012                      0         CQU
240 2012                      0         CQU
241 2012                      0          UQ
242 2012                      0         CQU
243 2012                      1         QUT
244 2012                      0         USQ
245 2012                      0         JCU
246 2012                      0         USQ
247 2012                      0         USQ
248 2012                      3     QUT/ACU
249 2012                      0          UQ
250 2012                      1     QUT/ACU
251 2012                      0         USQ
252 2012                      1         QUT
253 2012                      2     QUT/ACU
254 2012                      1         QUT
255 2012                      0          UQ
256 2012                      0          GU
257 2012                      1         CQU
258 2012                      3          GU
259 2012                      0         CQU
260 2012                      0         USQ
261 2012                      1         JCU
262 2012                      1         USC
263 2012                      0         USQ
264 2012                      1         JCU
265 2012                      0     USQ/USC
266 2012                      0         JCU
267 2012                      0         JCU
268 2012                      0         JCU
269 2012                      0          UQ
270 2012                      1         CQU
271 2012                      0         USC
272 2012                      0          GU
273 2012                      0         CQU
274 2012                      1         QUT
275 2012                      0         USC
276 2012                      3          GU
277 2012                      1         JCU
278 2012                      0          UQ
279 2012                      0          UQ
280 2012                      3          GU
281 2012                      0          UQ
282 2012                      3          GU
283 2012                      0         CQU
284 2012                      0         JCU
285 2012                      0         JCU
286 2012                      3          GU
287 2012                      0         USC
288 2012                      0          GU
289 2012                      0         USQ
290 2012                      1         QUT
291 2012                      0         JCU
292 2012                      0         USC
293 2012                      0         USC
294 2012                      0         QUT
295 2012                      3          GU
296 2012                      0         CQU
297 2012                      0         JCU
298 2012                      3          GU
299 2012                      0         USQ
300 2012                      1         QUT
301 2012                      0         USQ
302 2012                      0         JCU
303 2012                      0          UQ
304 2012                      0         QUT
305 2012                      1         CQU
306 2012                      0         USQ
307 2012                      0          UQ
308 2012                      1     QUT/ACU
309 2012                      0         CQU
310 2012                      2         JCU
311 2012                      3          GU
312 2012                      0         JCU
313 2012                      0          GU
314 2012                      0          GU
315 2012                      0         USQ
316 2012                      0          UQ
317 2012                      0         USQ
318 2012                      0          GU
319 2012                      0         JCU
320 2012                      0          UQ
321 2012                      0         USQ
322 2012                      1         JCU
323 2012                      1         QUT
324 2012                      0         JCU
325 2012                      0          GU
326 2012                      0     USQ/USC
327 2012                      0          GU
328 2012                      0         USQ
329 2012                      0          UQ
330 2012                      3          GU
331 2012                      1         JCU
332 2012                      0         CQU
333 2012                      3          GU
334 2011                      0         USC
335 2011                      0         JCU
336 2011                      0     QUT/ACU
337 2011                      0         JCU
338 2011                      0         JCU
339 2011                      0         CQU
340 2011                      0          GU
341 2011                      2          GU
342 2011                      0         JCU
343 2011                      1         CQU
344 2011                      0          UQ
345 2011                      0         JCU
346 2011                      0     QUT/ACU
347 2011                      0         QUT
348 2011                      0          UQ
349 2011                      0     QUT/ACU
350 2011                      0         CQU
351 2011                      0         CQU
352 2011                      0          UQ
353 2011                      0         CQU
354 2011                      0         QUT
355 2011                      0         USQ
356 2011                      0         JCU
357 2011                      0         USQ
358 2011                      0         USQ
359 2011                      1     QUT/ACU
360 2011                      0          UQ
361 2011                      1     QUT/ACU
362 2011                      0         USQ
363 2011                      0         QUT
364 2011                      0     QUT/ACU
365 2011                      1         QUT
366 2011                      0          UQ
367 2011                      0          GU
368 2011                      1         CQU
369 2011                      2          GU
370 2011                      0         CQU
371 2011                      0         USQ
372 2011                      0         JCU
373 2011                      0         USC
374 2011                      0         USQ
375 2011                      1         JCU
376 2011                      0     USQ/USC
377 2011                      0         JCU
378 2011                      0         JCU
379 2011                      0         JCU
380 2011                      0          UQ
381 2011                      1         CQU
382 2011                      0         USC
383 2011                      0          GU
384 2011                      0         CQU
385 2011                      1         QUT
386 2011                      0         USC
387 2011                      2          GU
388 2011                      1         JCU
389 2011                      0          UQ
390 2011                      0          UQ
391 2011                      2          GU
392 2011                      0          UQ
393 2011                      2          GU
394 2011                      0         CQU
395 2011                      0         JCU
396 2011                      0         JCU
397 2011                      2          GU
398 2011                      0         USC
399 2011                      0          GU
400 2011                      0         USQ
401 2011                      1         QUT
402 2011                      0         JCU
403 2011                      0         USC
404 2011                      0         USC
405 2011                      0         QUT
406 2011                      2          GU
407 2011                      0         CQU
408 2011                      0         JCU
409 2011                      2          GU
410 2011                      0         USQ
411 2011                      1         QUT
412 2011                      0         USQ
413 2011                      0         JCU
414 2011                      0          UQ
415 2011                      1         QUT
416 2011                      0         CQU
417 2011                      0         USQ
418 2011                      0          UQ
419 2011                      0     QUT/ACU
420 2011                      0         CQU
421 2011                      1         JCU
422 2011                      2          GU
423 2011                      0         JCU
424 2011                      0          GU
425 2011                      0          GU
426 2011                      0         USQ
427 2011                      0          UQ
428 2011                      0         USQ
429 2011                      0          GU
430 2011                      0         JCU
431 2011                      0          UQ
432 2011                      0         USQ
433 2011                      0         JCU
434 2011                      0         QUT
435 2011                      0         JCU
436 2011                      0          GU
437 2011                      0     USQ/USC
438 2011                      0          GU
439 2011                      0         USQ
440 2011                      0          UQ
441 2011                      2          GU
442 2011                      0         JCU
443 2011                      0         CQU
444 2011                      2          GU
```

Note: my copied and pasted data, that include row numbers, is not showing correctly.